# Is there a layer rendering order issue when using QgsQuick? Like what layers are on top?

Tags: vector, gis, raster, layer, qgis

I'm using QgsQuick in one of my development projects.

I use QGIS Desktop to setup my map environment(.qgs file). When running my project using QgsQuick, it seems that the raster image layers are always rendered on top of the vector layers. Even though I've set the rendering order in QGIS Desktop so that the vector layers should show on top.

Has anyone had this issue?

I've seen this issue with qgis 3.4.4 and version 3.22. Same issue on Windows and Linux.

Is the QgsQuick tool still being maintained by QGIS?

Do anyone know if the QgsQuick qml tool is widely used?

I've tried it on windows and Linux.

When opening my development project without making use of the QgsQuick, It runs correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Pieter